# function to pointer reference conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I am wondering why the following code is correct:

```
void foo(){}
void foo2(void(*)()){};
void foo3(void(*)()&){};

int main(){
  foo; // type void(&)() lvalue
  foo2(foo); // void(&)() -> void(*)() function to pointer conversion
  foo3(foo); // ?? conversion
}
```

According to the `function to pointer` conversion [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.func)

> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”.
> The result is a pointer to the function.

The conversion is fine from the void(&)() to the void(*)(), but not void(*)()&.

What is the reason for this code snippet (especially line with ??) to be correct?

Comment: I suspect that it is the same as for `void(*)()const`: method to function "conversion" type (`void(C::*)()&` -> `void(*)()&`).

Comment: There is no current pointer to `foo` on which you can take a reference?

Comment: error from clang btw [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/670c7d8fce823ec0): *"pointer to function type cannot have '&' qualifier"*

Comment: @Jarod42 you are right, Probably it's not permitted then. GCC does not issue any type of warning.

Comment: With some `using`, gcc provides error [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2722bb5d2d7d2d4), and its behavior seems to be a bug for me...

Comment: As Jarod42’s comment indicates: that `&` is a ref-qualifier, not a reference declarator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter of `foo3` which is `void(*)()&` is actually a **function pointer with a ref-qualifier**. This is not allowed by the standard.

The C++17 standard draft n4659 states :

[[dcl.fct]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#6)

> A function type with a cv-qualifier-seq **or a ref-qualifier** (including a type named by typedef-name) **shall appear only as**:
>
> (6.1) — the function type for a non-static member function,
>   (6.2) — the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
>   (6.3) — the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or alias-declaration,
>   (6.4) — the type-id in the default argument of a type-parameter, or
>   (6.5) — the type-id of a template-argument for a type-parameter.

The parameter of `foo3` does not meet any of the criteria above. The closest to what you are trying to do is (6.2).

So you can have this instead:

```
void foo(){}
class C {
public:
    void foo1() & {}
};
void foo2(void(*)()){};
void foo3(void(C::*)()&){};

int main(){
  (void) foo; 
  foo2(foo); 
  foo3(&C::foo1); 
}
```

This compiles on both GCC and Clang.
[Demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/nOUQw_).

Comment: A note like this generally describes something that is normatively stated elsewhere in a less accessible way. It's unusual for it to purport to form a rule of its own (because that would have no legal meaning at all). As such, I expect we'll find that compilers have no leeway at all but we'd need to find the normative cause.

Comment: Also where is the reference to function type?